# Eclipse: Compare with -> Unhandled loop exception

Tags: eclipse, git, compare, runnable, helios

I downloaded the Last Eclipse Helios Version and set it up to use it with GIT.
I also downloaded and installed the last JAVA JRE8.

Everytime i want to compare a file with the GIT-Index (Right click on the file - Compare with - Git index) I get an eclipse exception and an 'Editor' pops up, with no content.

Is there something wrong with my installed Java or Eclipse?

I also cannot update eclipse using 'Help - Check for updates'...

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.3.2.201404171909-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.3.2.201404171909-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.3.2.201404171909-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.3.2.201404171909-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

Message: Unhandled loop exception

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.core.format.FormatPreferencesSupport.verifyValidity(FormatPreferencesSupport.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.core.format.FormatPreferencesSupport.getIndentationChar(FormatPreferencesSupport.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.configuration.PHPStructuredTextViewerConfiguration.getIndentPrefixes(PHPStructuredTextViewerConfiguration.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.configure(StructuredTextViewer.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.MergeSourceViewer.configure(MergeSourceViewer.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.TextMergeViewer$ContributorInfo.internalSetDocument(TextMergeViewer.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.TextMergeViewer$ContributorInfo.setDocument(TextMergeViewer.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.TextMergeViewer.updateContent(TextMergeViewer.java:2569)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.ContentMergeViewer.internalRefresh(ContentMergeViewer.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.compare.ContentMergeViewer.inputChanged(ContentMergeViewer.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareViewerSwitchingPane.setInput(CompareViewerSwitchingPane.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareContentViewerSwitchingPane.setInput(CompareContentViewerSwitchingPane.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.internalSetContentPaneInput(CompareEditorInput.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.access$8(CompareEditorInput.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput$11.run(CompareEditorInput.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.feed1(CompareEditorInput.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.feedInput(CompareEditorInput.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.createContents(CompareEditorInput.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor.createCompareControl(CompareEditor.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor.access$6(CompareEditor.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor$3.run(CompareEditor.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    ... 23 more

eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product -clean
```

Comment: The cannot update message is telling you that Eclipse 3.7 is required for Git (Helios is 3.6 and seriously old, 4.3 is current with 4.4 due out shortly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [324051](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324051) which was closed fixed 4 years ago. It looks like it needs a newer version of Eclipse than Helios.

Comment: I got Eclipse-Version Kepler and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your help.